# Creating a comment-like box in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a comment and like box like the one shown in this tutorial what are the main changes I need to make in order to make it work with ASP.NET Core 3.1

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-create-a-comment-box-session-as-like-facebook-comment-in-asp-net

Comment: The article you linked-to is for WebForms, which is a two-decades-old obsolete web-platform. It's very, very different to modern web frameworks so things aren't directly portable, i.e. there are no "main changes" you can make to the article because effectively zero code is reusable in ASP.NET Core (even the example SQL Server stored-procedure code is incredibly outdated).

Comment: ohh so can u help me with a link or resource in creating comments ?  im new to asp.net core

Comment: I am not available to assist with 1:1 tutoring, sorry.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi @Suhaib alnaji, any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? If not, could you please follow up to let me know? Refer to: 
 [How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235.) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To create a Facebook-like comment box in ASP.NET Core， I do a demo to make it, referring to official documentation to configure database:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

1.To Create the comment box, we need to create User, Reply, Comment models to add some tables ,and add some ViewModels.

User.cs:

```
public class User

    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreateOn { get; set; }
       
    }
```

Reply.cs:

```
public class Reply

    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreateOn { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public int CommentId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CommentId")]
        public virtual Comment Comment{get;set;}
    }
```

Comment.cs:

```
public class Comment

    {

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreateOn { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }  

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Reply> Replies { get; set; }
        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

LoginVM.cs:

```
public class LoginVM
    {
        [Required]
        [Key]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

RegisterVM.cs:

```
 public class RegisterVM
    {
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Compare("Password")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

ReplyVM.cs:

```
public class ReplyVM
    {
        public string Reply { get; set; }
        public int CID { get; set; }
    }
```

2. Installs the EF Core package
   From the Tools menu, select NuGet Package Manager >  Manage NuGet Packages for solution.

[Note]My core3.1 installed 3.1.21 version

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies

Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.JSON

3. creates a database context class: Models/ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) :base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Reply> Replies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<commentbox.ViewModels.LoginVM> LoginVM { get; set; }

    }
```

4.Add codes in Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSession();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContext")));
        }
```

5.Add app.UseSession();  in Startup.Configure

6.Add a connection string to the appsettings.json file:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "ApplicationDbContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=ApplicationDbContext-1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"}
```

7.In the Package Manager Console (PMC), enter the following commands separately:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
Update-Database
```

8.Add HomeController to set userId=0 when people first Login without register, add AccountController to manage user login or not, add  ChatRoomController to manage user post comments or reply.

HomeController.cs:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    { ....

        public IActionResult Index()


        {
            ISession session = HttpContext.Session;
            session.SetInt32("UserId", 0);
            return View();
        }
      ...

}
```

AccountController.cs:

```
public class AccountController : Controller

    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;
        public AccountController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            db = context;
        }
        
        //GET:Account/Register
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }
        //GET:Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Register(RegisterVM obj)
        {
            bool UserExistis=db.Users.Any(x=>x.UserName==obj.UserName);
            if(UserExistis)
            {
                ViewBag.UserNameMessage = "This UserName is already in use, try another";
                return View();
            }
            bool EmailExistis = db.Users.Any(y => y.Email == obj.Email);
            if (EmailExistis)
            {
                ViewBag.EmailMessage = "This Email is already in use, try another";
                return View();
            }
            //if username and email  is unique, then we save or register the user
            User u = new User();
            u.UserName = obj.UserName;
            u.Password = obj.Password;
            u.Email = obj.Email;
            u.ImageUrl = "";
            u.CreateOn = DateTime.Now;

            db.Users.Add(u);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index","ChatRoom");
        }
        //GET:Account/Login
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
        //GET:Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login(LoginVM obj)
        {
            bool existis = db.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == obj.UserName&&u.Password==obj.Password);
            if(existis)
            {
                ISession session = HttpContext.Session;
                session.SetInt32("UserId", db.Users.Single(x => x.UserName == obj.UserName).Id);     
                return RedirectToAction("Index","ChatRoom");
            }
            //if invalid credentials
            ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Credentials!";
            return View();
        }
    }
```

ChatRoomController.cs:

```
 public class ChatRoomController: Controller

    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;
        public ChatRoomController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            db = context;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var comments = db.Comments.Include(x => x.Replies).ThenInclude(x=>x.User).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateOn)
                .ToList();
            return View(comments);
        }  

        //Post:ChatRoom/PostReply
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostReply(ReplyVM obj)
        {
           
            ISession session = HttpContext.Session;
            int userId =(int)session.GetInt32("UserId");

            if (userId==0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }
            Reply r = new Reply();
            r.Text = obj.Reply;
            r.CommentId = obj.CID;
            r.UserId =userId;
            r.CreateOn = DateTime.Now;
            db.Replies.Add(r);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        //Post:ChatRoom/PostComment
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostComment(string CommentText)
        {
            ISession session = HttpContext.Session;
            int userId = (int)session.GetInt32("UserId");
            if (userId == 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }
            Comment c = new Comment();
            c.Text = CommentText;
            c.CreateOn = DateTime.Now;
            c.UserId = userId;
            db.Comments.Add(c);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

9.Add views: Login.cshtml(for Login action in AccountController), Register.cshtml(for Register action in AccountController), index.cshtml(for Index action in ChatRoomController).

Login.cshtml:

```
@model commentbox.ViewModels.LoginVM


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
}

<h1>Login</h1>
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Login">
            <h4 class="text-danger">@ViewBag.Message</h4>
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Register.cshtml:

```
@model commentbox.ViewModels.RegisterVM


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}
<h1 class="text-success">Register User</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Register">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
                <p class="text-danger">@ViewBag.UserNameMessage </p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                <p class="text-danger">@ViewBag.EmailMessage </p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary"  style="border-radius:20px"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<commentbox.Models.Comment>


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<h2 class="text-success text-center"> someone's post or some other things</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostComment", "ChatRoom", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" name="CommentText" placeholder="Type new comment..."
           style="width:700px; height:60px; font-size:20px; margin-top:10px" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Post Comment" class="btn btn-success "
           style="margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px " />
}
<table class="table text-center">

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var comment in Model)
        {
            <tr style="border:1px solid black;">
                <td>
                    <span style="margin-right:15px;font-size:16px;color:green">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.User.UserName)
                    </span>


                    <span style="font-size:20px">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.Text)
                    </span>
                    <span style="margin-left:10px">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.CreateOn)
                    </span>
                    @foreach (var reply in comment.Replies)
                    {
                        <br />
                        <span style="margin-right:15px;font-size:16px;color:blue">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => reply.User.UserName)
                        </span>
                        <span style="font-size:19px">
                            @reply.Text
                        </span>
                        <span style="margin-left:10px">
                            @reply.CreateOn
                        </span>

                    }
                    <br />
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("PostReply", "ChatRoom", FormMethod.Post))
                    {<input type="text" name="Reply" placeholder="Type  reply..."
                            style="width:100%; height:60px; font-size:20px; margin-top:10px" />
                        <br />
                        <input type="hidden" name="CID" value="@comment.Id" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Post Reply" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top :10px" />
                    }

                </td>


            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

10.Add link in _Layout.cshtml.

```
                        <li class="nav-item">    
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">Register</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Login</a>
                        </li>
```